# ImportError: cannot import name 'db' from partially initialized module 'application'

Tags: python, flask

Im trying to set up a Flask factory, first time I have tried. I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/grahammorby/Documents/GitHub/tagr-api/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 219, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/Users/grahammorby/Documents/GitHub/tagr-api/wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from application import init_app
  File "/Users/grahammorby/Documents/GitHub/tagr-api/application/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from application.users import users_blueprint
  File "/Users/grahammorby/Documents/GitHub/tagr-api/application/users.py", line 3, in <module>
    from application.models import User
  File "/Users/grahammorby/Documents/GitHub/tagr-api/application/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import db, ma
ImportError: cannot import name 'db' from partially initialized module 'application' (most likely due to a circular import) (/Users/grahammorby/Documents/GitHub/tagr-api/application/__init__.py)
```

So I have a file called wsgi.py

```py
from application import init_app

app = init_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

and then I have an application folder which has a **init.py** file in it

```py
from flask import Flask
from config import Config

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager

from application.users import users_blueprint
from application.apps import apps_blueprint

# Globally accessible libraries
db = SQLAlchemy()
ma = Marshmallow()
bcrypt = Bcrypt()
JWTManager = JWTManager()


def init_app():
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)
    app.config.from_object(Config)

    # Setup plugins
    db.init_app(app)
    ma.init_app(app)
    bcrypt.init_app(app)
    JWTManager.init_app(app)

    with app.app_context():
        # Blueprints
        return app
```

this is models.py:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from . import db, ma

class App(db.model):
    __tablename__ = "apps"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    app_name = Column(String(64))
    icon = Column(String(255))


class AppSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ("id", "app_name", "icon")


app_schema = AppSchema()
apps_schema = AppSchema(many=True)
```

So I have tried to remove the db altogether to see if it builds but it just keeps giving me the same error. Im loaded into my venv and all seems like it should work.

```py
def init_app():
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)
    app.config.from_object(Config)

    # Setup plugins
    db.init_app(app)
    ma.init_app(app)
    bcrypt.init_app(app)
    JWTManager.init_app(app)
    Migrate = init_app(app, db)

    from models import User, App

    with app.app_context():
        # Blueprints
        from application.users import users_blueprint
        from application.apps import apps_blueprint

        app.register_blueprint(users_blueprint)
        app.register_blueprint(apps_blueprint)

        return app
```

Comment: Please show the **whole** error traceback message.  Some module somewhere is trying to import db, and you have not shared that code.

Comment: I have removed all imports which i thought wouldn't bring all the extras modules in?

Comment: Please show the other code files (or at least their imports). Otherwise, all I can suggest is a general answer below.

Comment: You appear to have a circular import between you __init__.py module and your blueprints. Try moving the import of the blueprints from the main body of your to within the init_app function.

Answer (score 1):

From the code provided, there appears to be a circular import.

Consider an example: module A and module B.

If module A depends on something module B contains, and module B depends on something module A has, then we would have a **circular import**. Try putting those dependencies into another file, so both can share the functionality. If you would like a more detailed diagnosis, please provide more code (preferably from those files that the interpreter is complaining about).